# In Python, how do I join two arrays by key column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two arrays (after import numpy as np),

```
a=np.array([['a',1],['b',2]],dtype=object)
```

and

```
b=np.array([['b',3],['c',4]],dtype=object)
```

How do I get:

```
c=np.array([['a',1,None],['b',2,3],['c',None,4]],dtype=object)
```

Basically, an join using the first column as key.

Thanks

Comment: That looks like a really specific result. Especially since you want None in that specific order.

Comment: How big are your arrays ?  Could you use [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) + pure python (@Sven), then numpy after that ?

Answer (score 7):

A pure Python approach to do this would be

```
da = dict(a)
db = dict(b)
c = np.array([(k, da.get(k), db.get(k))
              for k in set(da.iterkeys()).union(db.iterkeys())])
```

But if you are using NumPy, your arrays are probably big, and you are looking for a solution with a better performance.  In this case, I suggest using some real database to do this, for example the [`sqlite3` module](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) that comes with Python.

Comment: I found using `sqlite3` was best. Building functionality based on that module is working wonders for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found is using pandas, which handles joins very well, and pandas objects convert to/from numpy arrays easily.